# Google calendar function deletes all my events after passing unique id

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

Google Calendar's `delete function` deletes all my events from the Google calendar and I don't know why this happens. Any help would be appreciated. I called `deleteevent` function in delete anchor.

```
$id = 'unique event id';

<a href="<?php $this->deleteevent($id);?>">Delete</a>    

function deleteevent()
{
    $cal->events->delete('primary', $id1) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined your function with an incoming event and your callback to google is using $id1.

You need to change your code to be a little like this

```
$id = 'unique event id';

<a href="<?php deleteevent($id);?>">Delete</a>    

function deleteevent($inboundid)
{
    $cal->events->delete('primary', $inboundid) 
}
```

This however won't work on clicking of the deletion link it'll just execute the function every page load. You need some form of event to call the function on link click be it a get/post or an ajax query.

Also you don't need $this-> in there unless all this code is within a class.